# Nodemon - run event conditionally if change occured in another watched lib

Tags: node.js, nodemon

Suppose we have our `mainapp` and a `subapp`.

```
project
  - mainapp
    - src
      - app.js
      - package.json
  - subapp
    - src
      - app.js
      - package.json
```

Here is a `watch` script in `mainapp` that watches for changes in both apps:

```
nodemon --watch src/ app.js -e ts --watch '../subapp/src/*' -e ts
```

This script works.

However, **what I want it to do is that if a change occured in `subapp`, I first want to run a script from `subapp/src/package.json` and then restart the `subapp`.**

I also have a `nodemon.json` file with a restart script. This is a command in `subapp`:

```
{
  "events": {
    "restart": "npm run build"
  }
}
```

to reiterate, I only want `npm run build` to run IF a change occured ONLY in `subapp`.

Is this possible to do with nodemon? If so, how?